# How to know the exact error from Travis build

Tags: android, travis-ci, logcat, android-instrumentation

Currently, I am facing a travis CI build error in my repository [here](https://travis-ci.org/openmrs/openmrs-contrib-android-client/builds/468676006#L2347), and I'd really like to know the exact issue as `connectedCheck` only outputs

```
Tests on test(AVD) - 5.1.1 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

in Travis, and the tests are passing just fine in my own machine.

This is my current .travis.yml :

```
sudo: required
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-22
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-27.0.3
    - android-27
    - android-22
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}
  licenses:
      - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
      - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
      - 'google-gdk-license-.+'

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

  - ./build.sh
  - ./gradlew connectedCheck coveralls

  on:
    tags: true
```

I want to know how to get a more detailed error message (e.g. line number).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's right there in logs, according to travis job, here's the test which is failing `test_shouldConvertMonthsToYears` due to `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am aware of this. Is there a way to know where the NullPointerException is coming from (e.g. line number is useful info)? As this test passes on my machine.